# How to add additional attributes to standard XAML elements?

Tags: wpf, xaml

This button click method launches a Window called "(assemblyname).Reports" when a button with Content "Reports" is clicked:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
    Type type = this.GetType();
    Assembly assembly = type.Assembly;
    Window window = (Window)assembly.CreateInstance(String.Format("{0}.{1}", type.Namespace, button.Content));
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

But I want the Content attribute value of the button to be able to change, e.g. it might change to "Stock Reports" but I still want the clicking of the button to launch "(assemblyname).Reports".

Is there a way to add attributes to the button tag, e.g. "TheWindowFileName"?

```
<Button x:Name="btnReports" Content="Stock Reports" TheWindowFileName="Reports"/>
```

If not, how else can I add additional information to my button elements which I can read and process in code behind?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Certainly you can use [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) to add extra attributes to XAML elements, but for what you need you could probably just use the existing [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) property:

```
<Button x:Name="btnReports" Content="Stock Reports" Tag="Reports"/>
```

Comment: very interesting, works great for what I needed, is it possible to add more than one of these? this MSDN page isn't that clear on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx

Comment: No, Tag is a property just like Width or Content - it can only be used once. To add your own, follow the attached properties link.

Answer (score 1):

Using Attached Property here can be an overkill but instead you can try to encapsulate your button behavior in a [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) and pass the data you want to use in the command as a `CommandParameter`. That should do the trick.